# Multiple forms on IE 8 issues

Tags: asp.net, forms, web, internet-explorer-8

I have a asp.net web application in which I am using multiple forms. The site works fine on all the browsers except IE 8. On IE 8, the complete page breaks and the positioning of the UI elements is also getting disturbed.

Is there any way to fix this problem for IE 8??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, the website seems to have misplaced your examples.

Comment: Even i m also facing same problem pls anyone can help us in this.. then it will be great...